# How to change text format using wildcards in VBA

Tags: vba, wildcard

Our Word documents have several occurrences of the text "Division XX" where XX ranges from 00 thru 99. I need to boldface these using VBA. Below is some code I adopted which gets me part way

```
With mDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Find
       .Forward = True
       .Wrap = wdFindStop
       .Format = False
       .MatchCase = False
       .MatchWholeWord = False
       .MatchWildcards = False
       .MatchSoundsLike = False
       .MatchAllWordForms = False
       .Replacement.Font.Bold = True

       .Execute FindText:="Division", Format:=True, ReplaceWith:="Division", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
```

However, it doesn't select or highlight the " XX". I tried and failed to use wildcards because it wasn't clear to me what to use for the ReplaceWith value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()

    With ThisDocument.Range.Find

           .Forward = True
           .Wrap = wdFindStop
           .Format = False
           .MatchCase = False
           .MatchWholeWord = False
           .MatchWildcards = True '<<**
           .MatchSoundsLike = False
           .MatchAllWordForms = False
           .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
           'Find instances of "Division" followed by space then at least one digit
           .Execute FindText:="Division [0-9]{1,}", Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With
End Sub
```

See: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for me, I think because my text is in the cell of a table. It appears as though Work won't search with wildcards in a table cell. As a test, I tried doing a find/replace with wildcards using Word's interface and sure enough it ignored the text cells.

Comment: I only used document.range as a shortcut while testin - you need to edit my code to suit your use case...

Comment: I just tested my code as-is on a document with a table, and it did bold all instances of "Division ###", even those in a table.  If you only want that table to be affected then use `With mDoc.Tables(1).Range.Find`

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong earlier but tested again and its working, even for text in cells.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
Option Compare Text
Dim Search as Variant
For Each Search In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Search.Value Like "Division*" Then
        Search.Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next Search
```

Hope this helps